# How to handle a custom error message for Slack dialog box

Tags: node.js, slack

I am writing a sample app to understand the behavior of slack dialog box.
For a specific text field, how I can show the warning/error message on dialog box itself on the top, after clicking the Ok button.

for example, 
a Name field accept no special character, If user enters special character and press OK, how the dialog box remain open with error, "No special characer allowed" at the top. [Red box]

Any help would be appreciated. 
I am using nodejs for the development purposes..

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that it is not possible! Slack currently allow validation message below the input element as [documented here.](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#displaying_errors)

But, we can have a workaround by [updating](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#updating_views) or [pushing](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#pushing_views) view modal with the help of API. You need to update/push a modal view similar to [this](https://api.slack.com/tools/block-kit-builder?mode=modal&view=%7B%22type%22%3A%22modal%22%2C%22title%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22My%20App%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22submit%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Submit%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22close%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Cancel%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22blocks%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22%3Awarning%3A%20*%60No%20special%20characer%20allowed.%60*%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22input%22%2C%22element%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text_input%22%7D%2C%22label%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Label%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%5D%7D). Hope this work's for your use case.

Comment: Your response is correct based on the documentation provided, but I am using the old ways of developing it. 

I am using this page to develop my app, https://api.slack.com/dialogs 
Checked the response on the page to make this happen but not that intutive information. Needed to check if someone already handled such a scenario.